# debian 8 iptables-persistent

Tags: linux, service, debian, iptables

i have VPS Debian 8 jessie x64 stable release. After installation im trying to configure iptables (like in debian 7).

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

executed succesefully, some packets were installed. but when im trying

```
service iptables-persistent start
```

im getting an error that says thar service iptables-persistent unrecognized

halp!

Comment: ```iptables-persistent``` is now ```netfilter-persistent```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/). Please delete this.

Answer (score 56):

**Persist IP Tables Debian/Ubuntu**

To persist any changes you make to your iptables rules, do the following.

Install iptables-persistent:

```
sudo apt-get install -y iptables-persistent
```

Make any changes you want to your iptables rules, eg

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -y iptables-persistent
```

The rules should persist after a reboot now.

**Extra Info**

The dpkg-reconfigure just causes iptables-persistent to do again what it does at install, which is to save the current iptables into a file using a command just like:

```
iptables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save >/etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

The iptables-persistent package causes the os to run something like the following on reboot.

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

Hope this helps : )

Comment: Curious vote downs. Is it off topic or something? If so wouldn't moving it somewhere on topic be a better idea? I thought I was being helpful : /

Comment: I voted it up to offset ;) I'm not an iptables expert but this looks helpful enough.

Comment: Option -y is not working on Debian 7.8 at `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -y iptables-persistent`

Comment: @ChamindaBandara Good point. -y isn't even an option for dpkg-reconfigure. Also, dpkg will ask even low priority questions, ignoring your default priority. If you want to have this run automated, you can reduce the likelihood of it bothering you with questions by using `-p critical`. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it's what I've been using.

Comment: Is this usable when using fail2ban? Won't it override fail2ban's rules?

Answer (score 10):

I just stumbled over OP's problem, too (and then his question); found the solution when looking at the [package description for iptables-persistent](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/iptables-persistent).  The new interface seems to be netfilter-persistent, that is use e.g.:

```
# invoke-rc.d netfilter-persistent save
```

At least that is what worked for me, HTH ...

Answer (score 4):

Update 8/7/16:  It depends on the distro.  The following comment content was entered in ignorance of whether the OP distro has a netfilter-persistent package.  My apologies.  My laptop distro (Mint) does not contain the netfilter-persistent package while my servers distros (Ubuntu 15+) do.

Original answer:
As Oliver correctly says, netfilter-persistent replaces iptables-persistent in Ubuntu. What worked with Ubuntu 15.04 was as follows:

Install it, then make sure it is running as a service:
    `service --status-all | grep netfilter-persistent`

If not running as a service, start it once for all time with:
    `invoke-rc.d netfilter-persistent start`

Then you must place a script someplace that will run when the network or its interfaces stop.  The important script content is simply:
    `invoke-rc.d netfilter-persistent save`

I put the script in `/etc/network/if-post-down.d` directory.  Don't forget to chmod it to executable.  If power outages are any likelihood, you could make a cron entry for the save command.

Comment: Sounds like he's saying netfilter is the base and iptables-persistent will extend from that. Very unclear. This is like Kremlinology, Ubuntu problems, another level above first world problems.

Answer (score 2):

iptables-persistent has been recommand on debian wiki many times .

to install it:

```
apt install iptables-persistent
```

iptables-persistent create the config files and use the package netfilter-persistent to reload or save iptables rules now

the iptables config files are at folder

```
/etc/iptables/rules.v4
/etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

the main manage tool is:

```
/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent # you should be root or call sudo to use it
```

when you want to change iptable rules , edit the config files then reload iptables rules

```
netfilter-persistent reload
```

or you can use iptables -I INPUT ... to change iptables rules first then save it to config files

```
netfilter-persistent save
```

if you want to clear the iptables rules ,you can use flush command

```
netfilter-persistent flush
```

Comment: Thank you for the  "netfilter-persistent reload".  This is helpful.  I kept rebooting my computer to load the edited rules because I couldn't find this command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in firewalld service. This is some kind of new firewall daemon which conflicts with netfilter(iptables)-persistent.

```
chkconfig firewalld off
```

and now all is working fine.

Disclaimer: this is not best practice, just a temporary wworkaround.